# When adding a publication in the Blueprint - Why is a 'Root' Structure group needed?

Tags: blueprint

I always wondered why it's impossible to inherit from a publication that doesn't have a root structure group?

I'm pretty sure in 5.2 this wasn't the case (i may have made this up, it was a long time ago), and that this was introduced around 5.3, 2009?

It always catches out developers new to Tridion, and personally can see advantages of inheriting content without the need for structures.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has *always* been a requirement in Tridion to have a Structure Group to enable Blueprinting. The right question to ask is "why doesn't Tridion create a structure group by default when I create a new publication?" and the answer is a complex and lengthy one...

The minor version of the reason why is that, back in the day when Tridion popped out of Arjan Van Rooijen's mind (and some others), and they decided to embrace XML and structured content as the way forward (to put this in context, we're talking **before** 1999), it was the intention that Tridion would be an Enterprise Content Management solution, not *only* WCM, in which case a Structure Group would not necessarily make sense.

Later on, when Blueprinting got added, Tridion's future was already focused on WCM more than ECM, and a Root Structure Group on the parent publication became a requirement to any blueprint tree. Adding this by default would cause compatibility issues, so there was a decision to not add it by default.

That's the short version. Should we add it into the product by default? Yes, I think so too, and it is in the roadmap with a rather low priority.

Comment: "why doesn't Tridion create a structure group by default when I create a new publication?" and the answer is a complex and lengthy one...

I still think it should be possible without a structure group, why not just be optional? - am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: Imagine the mess it would be when you created your Root SG later in the blueprint. Same mess as with creating a Publication without Root Folder. Dogmatic approach: because Blueprinting Rules state you must have only one Root Structure Group per blueprint tree.

Comment: It gets interesting when we also consider the "root" Categories & Keywords "organizational item" and External Content Libraries. The item that contains Categories isn't really a root, afaik. And we can configure ECLs lower in the BluePrint, right?

Comment: As I recall, this requirement goes back way further than 5.0 - maybe all the way back to the beginning of BluePrinting. Saying that it's necessary "to enable BluePrinting" is kind of ducking John's question though, as I'm sure many people would like to know the `technical` reason why it's necessary.

Comment: @AlvinReyes Categories & Keywords are a bit special, but they are available in every publication, so you have your "root" node there. With ECL it is a different story, because the ECL root node (mountpoint) isn't a Tridion item, it is added only in the UI. But trying to specify the same mountpoint in a single BluePrint would raise exceptions for sure.

Comment: @DominicCronin keep in mind there might not be a technical reason (read limitation) for it at all, it could just have been decided to make things clear from the start (preventing ppl from trying to create a root node in a BluePrint child which could become a conflict later on).

Comment: I recall that there /was/ a technical reason. For the definitive answer... cherche le Quebecois! :-)

Answer (score 6):

It always has been a requirement of a BluePrint structure to contain all root items, hence a root Structure Group is also required. The exact reason why I don't know, it's just a given fact.

The reason why there isn't a root Structure Group by default in a new Publication, is because in the R5.0 days there were customers who didn't use Tridion for a website and they didn't need Pages/Structure groups (and I guess they also didn't use BluePrinting).

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that if you will first create a blueprint and then will start creating root structure group you might end up creating it down the blueprint and it will mean that you will not be able to create another structure groups in the parent publications which will screw up all your implementation as you will have to delete your complete website just to create it higher up in the blueprint.

The other question is why root structure group is not created by default, like Building Blocks folder, for example? The answer is that back in the day idea was that Publication will not be the only type of Repository and so not all of the repositories will require it.

Comment: it might be that you want a 'root' called 'home' and another 'root' called 'base' - this is my point

Comment: Based on this last point, I'm rooting for the home team.