# Why can't I see the "Add Child" button in the Publication BluePrinting dialog?

Tags: 2011

I created a publication but in BluePrinting hierarchy I am not able to add a child Publication; the "Add" button does not appear.

I have the add button for a parents publications.

This is the image of the  parent publication
[image]

and this is of the the child publication

[image]

Comment: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/when-adding-a-publication-in-the-blueprint-why-is-a-root-structure-group-nee

Comment: I have created a root structure group, my problem is that i can add parents publications but for childPublications i didn't have the add button to add child Publications

Comment: That is by design - You can add parent and not child

Comment: I've reworded your question and title to make what you're asking clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Check the resolution of your machine if it is too high. Try to minimize and maximize the Browser window and also lower down the resolution of you machine and see if the "Add" button appears.

In case of high resolution machines, the "Add" button disappears from the GUI. Lowering down the resolution, makes it reappear.

Comment: Valid comment if it was about a missing button in general, but there is no "Add Child" button, so no matter what resolution you have, you will never ever see it.

Comment: Thanks Bart and yes that's correct, however, I posted the answer when the question was not that clear :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to directly "add" a Publication as a child of another. There are a couple of reasons for this that are immediately obvious (though it's likely that there are more):

1. The "Child Publications" section is recursive and doesn't just show direct children but all descendants. With this in mind, it's not explicitly clear what "adding a child" would mean.
2. There is no way to specify the inheritance priority (in the case of multiple-inheritance) without accounting for all of a Publication's parents. If you are looking at the parent and the child you're adding already has other parents, which should take priority?

You should open/select the desired child Publication and add your *new* Publication as a parent, instead.

Comment: The problem is that when i open my child publicayion i didn't have the Parent publication block i just have the child publication

Comment: Does the child Publication have at least one parent already (added at the time of creation)? I don't think you can add a parent to a Publication that is at the top of a BluePrint hierarchy.

Comment: I forget adding a parent when i created the publication and i want to modify it by: adding a parent to a child publication or adding a child in parent publication

Comment: @user1032 I think your only option is to recreate the child, I'm afraid. If that child has a lot of content already, you're in for a data migration task.

Comment: @user1032 to elaborate on what Ant P has basically already explained you, you can ONLY add a Parent to a Publication at the time of creation of that Publication. Unless that Publication is part of a BluePrint already, at which point you can add (or remove if applicable) a Parent.